# listener for multiple text field

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to call a text field listener from multiple field like this page

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newTextField.html#listener-optional

When user start to write something in input field,  handler function is called normally but closure that is located in handler is not called.

login.lua file like below:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- Forward declerations    
local userNameField

-- TextField Listener
local function fieldHandler( getObj )

     print( "This message is showing up :) " )

    -- Use Lua closure in order to access the TextField object
    return function( event )

        print( "This message is not showing up :( There is something wrong here!!!" )   

        if ( "began" == event.phase ) then
            -- This is the "keyboard has appeared" event
            getObj().text = ""
            getObj():setTextColor( 0, 0, 0, 255 )

        elseif ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        -- This event is called when the user stops editing a field:
        -- for example, when they touch a different field or keyboard focus goes away

            print( "Text entered = " .. tostring( getObj().text ) ) -- display the text entered
        elseif ( "submitted" == event.phase ) then
        -- This event occurs when the user presses the "return" key
        -- (if available) on the onscreen keyboard
        -- Hide keyboard
           native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )
        end
    end -- "return function()" 
end

local function userNameFieldHandler( event )
   local myfunc =  fieldHandler( function() return userNameField end ) -- passes the text field object
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

-- Create our Text Field
    userNameField = native.newTextField( display.contentWidth  * 0.1, display.contentHeight  * 0.5, display.contentWidth * 0.8, display.contentHeight * 0.08)

    userNameField:addEventListener( "userInput", userNameFieldHandler )
    userNameField.font = native.newFont( native.systemFontBold, 22 )
    userNameField.text = "User Name"
    userNameField:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0, 12 )
end
```

Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Corona, but your code is somewhat strange.

`userNameFieldHandler` doesn't do much, it just creates a handler calling `fieldHandler` and stores it in a local that is never used (`myfunc`). Are you sure you didn't mean this:

```
local function userNameFieldHandler( event )
   local myfunc =  fieldHandler( 
      function() return userNameField end ) -- passes the text field object
   return myfunc --<<<<--- added return
end
```

and maybe when you add the event listener you meant this (note the added `()`):

```
userNameField:addEventListener( "userInput", userNameFieldHandler() )
```